# Rendering in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js and one question I have is - 
Is it necessary to unmount a React Modal view before re-rendering it.

I am trying to call a react modal view as below. The modal shows up only the first time. But if the modal is unmounted before this render function is called, the Modal shows up.

```
render: function(options) {
    React.renderComponent(<ModalView id="ModalView" 
                         model={this.model}/>,$("#"+this.viewId)[0]);
},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should only call `React.renderComponent()` on the root component. To render a child component just return it in the `render` method.

```
render: function() {
        return <ModalView id="ModalView " model={this.model}/>;
}
```

And to answer your question, no, you shouldn't need to explicitly unmount anything. To trigger a render you either `setState`, `setProps` or `forceUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap modal? I have the same issue. Once rendered the componentDidMount would not be called. Hence modal would not be shown. I defined a onClose props to unmount the component on close.  If there is a better way i would be interested.

Comment: componentDidMount is called on initial render. componentDidUpdate is called on subsequest renders.